Trouble resolving this issue on iterm2: iconv
I'm trying to convert the encoding of a file using the iconv command on macOS, but I keep encountering the following error:
iconv: iconv_open(, -t): Invalid argument
Error converting string from  to UTF-8
details:
Operating System: macOS

This should be posted to [apple.se], not Stack Overflow - it's unrelated to programming, and specific to MacOS.

I wasn't aware of Ask Different. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

echo 'export LANG=en_US.UTF-8' >> ~/.zshrc

Run this and it should be fixed. Solution found here

O Thanks. Works fine!
